# python map vs itertools.map: Make the iterator version behave like the former

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

Consider the following example code. The example is given just to highlight the different functionality between `map` and `itertools.imap`. What I really want to do cannot be 
done with a list comprehension because in my real problem I am not creating a list but filling a larger numpy array with small arrays. So in response to the code below, please do not suggest: `[f(x) for x in range(3)]`

Example:

```
g = []

def f(x):
    g.append(x)
```

The results I get with `map` and itertools.map:

```
map(f, range(3)) # Results in g = [0,1,2]

itertools.imap(f, range(3)) # Does not change g
```

I want the `g` to change as done by the `map` function. 
However, I have heard that `map` will (or does) behave like 
`itertools.imap` in Python 3. Even though I am using Python 2.7 I want to learn the correct way of using an iterator version of the map. How do I use `itertools.imap` to achieve
the same outcome as I get with `map`?

I can do:

```
b = itertools.imap(f, range(3))
list(b) # This gives g = [0,1,2] if starting with an empty g.
```

Is this the correct way, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`itertools` functions return generators; they only operate when iterated over.  So `itertools.imap(f, range(3))` won't actually *do* anything until you run it to completion e.g. with `list`.

Per http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes, the most efficient way to consume an iterator is with a zero-length deque:

```
collections.deque(itertools.imap(f, range(3)), maxlen=0)
```

However, if you're calling a function for its side effects you should be using an imperative as opposed to functional syntax:

```
for i in range(3):
    f(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about collections.deque() and the tip about the loop. I will look into that. In this case I cannot use the loop because I eventually want to use picloud which requires me to use cloud.map if I want to run the jobs (one job for each value in the list) simultaneously. I know that cloud.map is different from in-built map. However, I wanted to keep the local version of the code and the one I run on picloud similar. Just to make sure I can use cloud.map later when I need it. Also, isn't map faster than a for-loop?

Comment: I disagree with always using an explicit loop, if performance is relevant the implicit loops of `map`, `imap` and list comprehensions are way faster.

Comment: @Curious2learn no, there's no reason to assume map is faster than a for loop (for example, `map` needs to collect its results, even if they're immediately thrown away).  I'd be cautious about applying `cloud.map`; it's possible that its approach to mutability of globals will not work well with your modifications to `g`.

Comment: @ecatmur http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html - implicid loops in C do offer a performance benefit according to the BDFL.

Comment: @l4mpi that's a pretty specialized case, where the overhead of looking up the loop function dominates the call overhead. Point taken, though.

Comment: @ectamur Thanks for the caution about cloud.map. I have not yet figured how to use it for a case such as this. But will keep your point in mind when I try to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `map()` incorrectly.  It should not be used for the side effects of the function call, but to transform an iterable.

You can use `list(itertools.imap(f, range(3)))` to get the behavior you want, but I would argue that you should change your entire approach to use a normal for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    f(i)
```

This makes it clear that the return values from the `f()` calls are not being used.

Comment: As far as I know `itertools.imap`, like `map`, uses an implied loop, which should be faster than an explicit one.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `map` in Python 2.x is the equivalent of `list(map(...))` in Python 3. That's it - nothing special...